# Implementing user-session management in Tornado?

Tags: python, security, session, proxy

How can I implement the user-session management in Tornado? I found this fork which supports it [github tornado](https://github.com/milancermak/tornado) but it has not been updated in 3 years!

I'm trying to implement a **ZAP** ([zaproxy](https://code.google.com/p/zaproxy)) like functionality to support user-session management using Tornado web framework.

Comment: here is [main repository](https://github.com/facebook/tornado).

Comment: The link I provided is a fork of that. It has a patch included for session management but its 3 years old.